# SharePoint Online / Teams site collection Configure search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, enterprise-search, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams and its site collection.

I want to create on its SharePoint a search experience page, with its search box, results webpart, refiners etc...

However when I edit the page, I can't see the Search Category to add the webparts

[image]

As an alternative, I've created a Enterprise search subsite. Now, here I have the default search box, navigation, results webparts etc.. but when I edit the webparts, the changes don't get applied when I save the page. Defaults options appear again, so I can't configure it. It seems as only default optiones were available.

Is there anyway to configure this? Maybe I need to activate some feature?

Comment: If you want those web parts in Team Sites, then activate Publishing Infrastructure feature.

Comment: Do you have custom scripts disabled on root site collection? http://mstechtalk.com/missing-web-part-features-office-365/

Answer (score 0):

Posting it as an answer for future use...

Do you have custom scripts disabled on root site collection? http://mstechtalk.com/missing-web-part-features-office-365

Comment: You could accept this reply as an answer. So that more people with similar issue will see it.